# Grails - get domain relationship id without fetching the whole object

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have, for example, the following domain objects:

```
class A {
   B b

static constraints = {
        b nullable: true
    }
}

class B {
}
```

Given instance of A, I would like to fetch only the id of B.

I tried the following, but received null every time:

```
def id = a.bId
```

Is it possible to fetch the id of b without doing `a.b.id` ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enhance your domain to use GORM based mapping hints (given to Hibernate) to accomplish this.

Your domain could look something like this:

```
class A {
  static hasOne = [b: B]
}

class B {
  // stuff
}
```

Using the `hasOne` will allow Hibernate to manage the association and thus allows you to use the `a.bId` notation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK, my problem is that A holds reference to anotherA (sort of a linked list). In this case it does not seem to work at all.

Comment: Is the example in your question updated to reflect your actual situation? Again, unless you use some type of hint for GORM/Hibernate it won't be able to just load the id (actually loading a proxy with just the Id but that's not important). The only other solution would be to write a specific query that uses projections/hql to return the raw id.